# How to override Magento 2 graphql resolver with custom plugin

Tags: magento2, php, dependency-injection, graphql, ecommerce-tracking

Im trying to override the resolver by using a plugin in Magento 2 to change text.

vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/CouponManagement.php - **I need to change this**

```
class ApplyCouponToCart implements ResolverInterface
 { ...
 public function resolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null)
{ ...
   /* Check current cart does not have coupon code applied */
    $appliedCouponCode = $this->couponManagement->get($cartId);
    if (!empty($appliedCouponCode)) {
        throw new GraphQlInputException(
            __('A coupon is already applied to the cart. Please remove it to apply another')
        );
    }
```

Here is my plugin **Vendor\Custom_Module\Plugin;**

```
class AfterApplyCouponToCart {

public function afterResolve(Field $field, $context, ResolveInfo $info, array $value = null, array $args = null) 
{ ...
   /* Check current cart does not have coupon code applied */
    $appliedCouponCode = $this->couponManagement->get($cartId);
    if (!empty($appliedCouponCode)) {
        throw new GraphQlInputException(
            __('**This is my new text which I need to update**')
        );
    }
```

Comment: So how do I change text within 
**throw new GraphQlInputException(
            __('A coupon is already applied to the cart. Please remove it to apply another')
        );**

Comment: can you share how to you solve this ? i have same problems, thank you if you answer my question

Answer (score 0):

since it is a public method you can override it using around plugin
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#around-methods